# Convert a set of number to list or array, the order of the numbers changes

Tags: python

When I have a set of numbers, I want to convert the set to a list or array, no matter what I use, the order of the number changes

```
x = {4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}
y = list(x)
y
```

and y becomes `[17, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12]`

Comment: Sets are inherently unordered - if converted to a list, the order is arbitrary. If you want order, don't use a set in the first place.

Comment: Python sets are not ordered. You can find some ordered set modules at pypi.org. Or, you can use dicts with a boring value such as `None` for values. dict is ordered.